# How to fetch Data From Same Key in Different array Parse iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

i am newbie in to Parse.com i try to Fetch data from Parse table with same key but value is Different like as

```
-(void)getdata
{
NSMutableArray *allObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger limit = 1000;
__block NSUInteger skip = 0;
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
[query whereKey:@"Type" containedIn:@[@"Temporary", @"Business"]];
[query setLimit: limit];
[query setSkip: skip];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        if (objects.count == limit) {

            skip += limit;
            [query setSkip: skip];
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                self.qpinname=[allObjects valueForKey:@"GPIN"];
                NSLog(@"Qpin Array %lu",(unsigned long)[self.qpinname count]);
                self.locationArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"Location"];
                self.latitude=[self.locationArray valueForKey:@"lat"];
                self.longitude=[self.locationArray valueForKey:@"lng"];
                self.address=[allObjects valueForKey:@"Address"];
                self.usernameArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"AddedBy"];
                [self getdata2];
                hudView.hidden=TRUE;
            }];
             }
             }
    else
    {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
             }
             }];
 }
-(void)getdata2
{
NSMutableArray *allObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger limit = 1000;
__block NSUInteger skip = 0;
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
[query whereKey:@"Type" equalTo:@"Personal"];
[query setLimit: limit];
[query setSkip: skip];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        if (objects.count == limit) {

            skip += limit;
            [query setSkip: skip];
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                self.lqpinname=[allObjects valueForKey:@"GPIN"];
                NSLog(@"Qpin Array %lu",(unsigned long)[self.lqpinname count]);
                self.llocationArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"Location"];
                self.llatitude=[self.llocationArray valueForKey:@"lat"];
                self.llongitude=[self.llocationArray valueForKey:@"lng"];
                self.laddress=[allObjects valueForKey:@"Address"];
                self.usernameArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"AddedBy"];
            }];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
}
```

Here i want to fetch data for same key but in different array but it is not working for me please give me solution for it.

thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the key and what is the array to you? You have an array of columns set up, do you not want to add another one to it since it's the same value (key)

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is what you want to do but:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
    [query whereKey:@"Type" containedIn:@[@"Temporary", @"Business", @"Personal"]];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

        if (!error && result.count)
        {
            for (PFObject *parseResponse in result)
            {
                if ([[parseResponse objectForKey:@"Type"] isEqual:@"Personal"])
                {
                    //the logic for data with Type = Personal
                }
                else
                {
                    //the logic for the data with other Types
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```